# Find unmatched rows of a table w.r.t another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, 'chem_qc_stage1' and 'chem_qc_stage2'. I want to show rows which are in 'chem_qc_stage1' and not in 'chem_qc_stage2' by using following query:

```
select * 
from (select chem_name,raw_mat,blnd_no 
        from chem_qc_stage1 
        where m_m_no='318') as tmp 
where not exists (select chem_name,raw_mat,blnd_no 
                    from chem_qc_stage2 
                    where m_m_no='318');
```

which gives me the below output:

```
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

but the individual queries gives me the below respective outputs:

```
select chem_name,raw_mat,blnd_no from chem_qc_stage2 where m_m_no='318';
+-----------+---------+---------+
| chem_name | raw_mat | blnd_no |
+-----------+---------+---------+
| HTPB      | YY      | TT      |
+-----------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

select chem_name,raw_mat,blnd_no from chem_qc_stage1 where m_m_no='318';
+-----------+---------+---------+
| chem_name | raw_mat | blnd_no |
+-----------+---------+---------+
| HTPB      | YY      | TT      |
| HTPB      | YY      | ZZ      |
| HTPB      | FF      | FF      |
+-----------+---------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I know that if I use 'raw_mat' and 'blnd_no' in where clause then it will give me the perfect output. But user doesn't know the values of these two attributes beforehand.

Here I'm attaching my table creation queries:

```
create table chem_qc_stage1 (chem_name varchar(20),m_m_no varchar(10),raw_mat varchar(10),blnd_no varchar(10));
create table chem_qc_stage2 (chem_name varchar(20),m_m_no varchar(10),raw_mat varchar(10),blnd_no varchar(10));
insert into chem_qc_stage1 values('HTPB','318','YY','TT');
insert into chem_qc_stage1 values('HTPB','318','YY','ZZ');
insert into chem_qc_stage1 values('HTPB','318','FF','FF');
insert into chem_qc_stage2 values('HTPB','318','YY','TT');
```

Please help me to find the solution that will gives me the unmatched rows of 'chem_qc_stage1' table; and sometime, 'chem_qc_stage2' table may stay empty also, then also the query should give the unmatched rows.

Comment: You have neglected to specify what results you want.  You have written a query and it returns the expected results given the data you have provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for `not exists` like this?

```
select s1.*
from chem_qc_stage1 s1
where not exists (select 1
                  from chem_qc_stage2 s2
                  where s2.chem_name = s1.chem_name and
                        s2.raw_mat = s1.raw_mat and
                        s2.blnd_no = s1.blnd_no and
                        s2.m_m_no = s1.m_m_no
                );
```

This can also be written using tuples assuming none of the values are `NULL`:

```
select s1.*
from chem_qc_stage1 s1
where (s1.chem_name, s1.raw_mat, s1.blnd_no, s1.m_m_no) not in
       (select s2.chem_name, s2.raw_mat, s2.blnd_n, s2.m_m_no
        from chem_qc_stage2 s2
       );
```